How to POST to GO HTTP server with size of the json unknow
I have HTTP server with a POST method in GO language and Im trying to tie it to the call from another service, but the size and structure of a json is unknown, or can vary. One call can be 10 repeated db model structs, but the next one can have be a struct where it has more fields and could have a different number of stucts in a single call - say 20. How do I go about unmarshalling it and shoving it into a database?
I have a function read json that doesnt really have a read limit, but do I pack it into a structure?
func (app *application) readJSON(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, data interface{}) error{
    maxBytes := 1024*1024 // one megabyte
    r.Body = http.MaxBytesReader(w, r.Body, int64(maxBytes))

    dec := json.NewDecoder((r.Body))

    dec.DisallowUnknownFields()

    err := dec.Decode(data)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    err = dec.Decode(&struct{}{})
    if err != io.EOF {
        return errors.New("body must only contain a single JSON value")
    }
  return nil
}


Does your API have an actual JSON spec, or is it truly freeform?

You should add examples of the data to the question. Repeated data is generally handled with arrays, I do not know what you are talking about here.

My API does have a JSON spec, and for the fields that are unused I guess I could declare as null and just include them even if they are unused. My question was along the lines whether I could not use a model type and simply have a fluid type that would adjust to the data being published in the POST call.   Now, how would I go about the unspecified number of object types within the call?

Each request has the same model type, but the will be unspecified number of models at each call. One call might have 20 identical models, but next call might have just 10.

Just declare the structure with json tags and Arrays where is the Problem not really understand. As @Gimby say add data examples

type Model struct {
ID    int json:"id"
Date time.Time json:"date"
OutputCurrent  int32    json:"OutputCurrent"
OutputCurr  int32    json:"OutputCurr"
MotorProtection  bool    json:"MotorProtection"
MotorTemperature int32       json:"MotorTemperature"
OutputFrequency   int32      json:"OutputFrequency"
Speed  int32   json:"Speed"
DCLinkVoltage int32 json:"DCLinkVoltage"
RatedLineVoltage int32 json:"RatedLineVoltage"
HeatsinkTemperature int32 json:"HeatsinkTemperature"
DriveType []DriveType json:"DriveType"
}

Can you add those data examples to the question but I think you are overthinking. Because if a Struct has the same attributes what will be the final output?

First things first: It might make more sense to wrap your handler into https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#MaxBytesHandler.
